# session variable becomes null on refreshing the template

Tags: python, django

i am trying to create a session variable named city....but when i call 'home' template the session becomes Null.

```
def home(request):  
    city = request.GET.get('city')
    request.session['city'] = city
    print city

    context = {
    }
    return render(request, "products/Home.html", context)
```

here is urls.py

```
url(r'^$', 'Plumpin.views.home', name='home'),
```

i am not able to understand this behaviour

help needed

Comment: Surely it's because you always set a value; so if `city` is not in the GET parameters the previous value will be overridden by None.

Comment: what can i do better with by code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are doing here, but it sounds like you just need to check that `city` is actually supplied before setting it.

```
city = request.GET.get('city')
if city:
    request.session['city'] = city
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel....i am trying to set the city session for first time and then if the session is there then no need to set it again.

Comment: Well, then check `request.session['city']`, no?